# How to create a parent/parent id colum for this flat data structure?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like so

```
ID  L1          L2              L3                  OBId                    OBDesc      ParentId
1   3501-072                                        3501-072-0102           building1   ?
2   3501-072    3501-072-0102                       3501-072-0102-0001      room2       ?
3   3501-072    3501-072-0102   3501-072-0102-0001  3501-072-0102-0001-0001 table1      ?
4   3501-072    3501-072-0102   3501-072-0102-0001  3501-072-0102-0001-0002 chair1      ?
5   3501-072    3501-072-0102                       3501-072-0102-0003      room3       ?
6   3501-072    3501-072-0102   3501-072-0102-0003  3501-072-0102-0003-0001 Table2      ?
7   3501-072    3501-072-0102   3501-072-0102-0003  3501-072-0102-0003-0002 chair3      ?
```

The structure is basically, table1 belongs to room2 in bulding1.

The columns L1,L2,L3 etc are the hierarchy levels that represent this.

The OBId is the unique number for each node in the hierarchy

I need a query that can poulate the ParentId with the ID for next nevel up in the node.

Any ideas welcomed...

I have a table like so

```
ID  L1          L2              L3                  OBId                    OBDesc      ParentId
1   3501-072                                        3501-072-0102           building1   ?
2   3501-072    3501-072-0102                       3501-072-0102-0001      room2       ?
3   3501-072    3501-072-0102   3501-072-0102-0001  3501-072-0102-0001-0001 table1      ?
4   3501-072    3501-072-0102   3501-072-0102-0001  3501-072-0102-0001-0002 chair1      ?
5   3501-072    3501-072-0102                       3501-072-0102-0003      room3       ?
6   3501-072    3501-072-0102   3501-072-0102-0003  3501-072-0102-0003-0001 Table2      ?
7   3501-072    3501-072-0102   3501-072-0102-0003  3501-072-0102-0003-0002 chair3      ?
```

The structure is basically, table1 belongs to room2 in bulding1.

The columns L1,L2,L3 etc are the hierarchy levels that represent this.

The OBId is the unique number for each node in the hierarchy

I need a query that can populate the ParentId with the ID for next nevel up in the node.

Any ideas welcomed...

-----UPDATE-----

In order to simplify the example, I failed to mention that there are a total of 10 potential levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are nulls in L2 and L3 rather than empty strings you could use COALESCE

```
SELECT COALESCE(L3,L2,L1) as Parent FROM tablename
```

otherwise you can use a case statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN isnull(L2,'') = '' then L1
            WHEN isnull(L3,'') = '' then L2
            ELSE L3
       END as Parent 
FROM tablename
```

**EDIT**
An update would look something like :

```
update tablename 
SET parent = CASE WHEN isnull(L2,'') = '' then L1
                WHEN isnull(L3,'') = '' then L2
                ELSE L3
             END
```

Comment: I like the idea. How could I write that in an UPDATE query to update my records?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the L1, L2, L3 structure is fixed (meaning the hierarchy doesn't go more than 3 levels deep), I would use the following approach: simply write one query to update the values for each level of the hierarchy. This approach breaks down if the hierarchy goes to 4 or 5 levels because the queries start to get unwieldy, but it should work fine for 3 levels. If I had to support many more levels of hierarchy (or variable levels), I would probably come up with a more generalized solution (that would probably make use of a `CURSOR`).

I put together the following example that should get you the results you are looking for. This example assumes that L2 and L3 are blank ('') and not NULL. One thing I noticed when putting this together is that the sample data you provided doesn't appear to be valid (L1 and L2 for records 2 and 5 are identical, which means it is possible for a child record to have 2 parent records), so I corrected it in my write up.

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    L1 VARCHAR(50),
    L2 VARCHAR(50),
    L3 VARCHAR(50),
    OBId VARCHAR(50),
    OBDesc VARCHAR(50),
    ParentID INT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(1, '3501-072', '', '', '3501-072-0102', 'building1', NULL)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(2, '3501-072', '3501-072-0102', '', '3501-072-0102-0001', 'room2', NULL)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(3, '3501-072', '3501-072-0102', '3501-072-0102-0001', '3501-072-0102-0001-0001', 'table1', NULL)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(4, '3501-072', '3501-072-0102', '3501-072-0102-0001', '3501-072-0102-0001-0002', 'chair1', NULL)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(5, '3501-072', '3501-072-0103', '', '3501-072-0103-0003', 'room3', NULL)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(6, '3501-072', '3501-072-0103', '3501-072-0103-0003', '3501-072-0102-0003-0001', 'Table2', NULL)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(7, '3501-072', '3501-072-0103', '3501-072-0103-0003', '3501-072-0102-0003-0002', 'chair3', NULL)

--Update records with no parent ID
UPDATE @myTable SET ParentID = NULL WHERE L2 = '' AND L3 = ''

--Update first level
UPDATE @myTable 
SET ParentID = (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM @myTable T2 
    WHERE 
        T2.L1 = T1.L1 
        AND T2.L2 = '' 
        AND T2.L3 = ''
) 
FROM @myTable T1
WHERE T1.L2 <> '' AND T1.L3 = ''

--Update second level
UPDATE @myTable 
SET ParentID = (
    SELECT ID FROM @myTable T2 
    WHERE 
        T2.L1 = T1.L1 
        AND T2.L2 = T1.L2 
        AND T2.L3 = ''
        AND T1.L2 <> ''
) 
FROM @myTable T1
WHERE T1.L2 <> '' AND T1.L3 <> ''

--Select results
SELECT ID, L1, L2, L3, ParentID FROM @myTable
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: There are 10 possible levels

Comment: You should update the question with that info. I would say it's relatively important.

Comment: OK thank you. I'll update the question. If you have chance, I would appreciate an updated answer if possible :)